# nutch Fetch failed with protocol status: exception(16), lastModified=0: Http code=403, url=https://www.modernfamilydental.net/

Tags: nutch

I am doing parsechecker for url `url=https://www.modernfamilydental.net/`
o/p
Fetch failed with protocol status: `exception(16), lastModified=0: Http code=403, url=https://www.modernfamilydental.net/`

May I know what is the issue and how to solve it. I tried changing the agent name but it did not work. Please help me.

**nutch-site.xml**

```xml
<property>
    <name>http.agent.name</name>
    <value>crawlbot</value>
</property> 
<property>
    <name>plugin.includes</name>
    <value>protocol-httpclient|urlfilter-regex|query-(basic|site|url|lang)|indexer-csv|nutch-extensionpoints|protocol-httpclient|urlfilter-regex|summary-basic|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)protocol-http|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika|metatags|text|js|feed)|index-(basic|anchor|more|metadata)</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>db.ignore.external.links</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>db.ignore.external.links.mode</name>
    <value>byDomain</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>fetcher.server.delay</name>
    <value>2</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>fetcher.server.min.delay</name>
    <value>0.5</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>fetcher.threads.fetch</name>
    <value>400</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>fetcher.max.crawl.delay</name>
    <value>10</value>
    <description> If the Crawl-Delay in robots.txt is set to greater than this value (in seconds) then the fetcher will skip this page, generating an error report. If set to -1 the fetcher will never skip such pages and will wait the amount of time retrieved from robots.txt Crawl-Delay, however long that might be. </description>
</property>
```

Comment: Please share your script so that we can better provide feedback. I took a look at the robots.txt of this site and it looks like it doesn't block /. So all is left to look at is your script to figure out if there is anything that could be triggering the server from giving you 403 forbidden response

Comment: if you are running nutch in EMR try to change region and run on new region or use some proxy services ... I think you have abused ***modernfamilydental*** domain and they seems to be blocking your requests. As @EdwardRomero mentioned in robots.txt it is clearly defined to allow root for all agents so no reason for 403..

Comment: please show your nutch conf for better suggestions

Comment: I have overwritten the nutch default conf this is my nutch conf that is nutch-site.xml

Comment: <property>
     <name>http.agent.name</name>
     <value>crawlbot</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>plugin.includes</name>
    <value>protocol-httpclient|urlfilter-regex|query-(basic|site|url|lang)|indexer-csv|nutch-extensionpoints|protocol-httpclient|urlfilter-regex|summary-basic|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)protocol-http|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika|metatags|text|js|feed)|index-(basic|anchor|more|metadata)</value>
</property>

Comment: <property>
 <name>db.ignore.external.links</name>
 <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>db.ignore.external.links.mode</name>
 <value>byDomain</value>
</property>

Comment: <property>
  <name>fetcher.server.delay</name>
  <value>2</value>
</property>

Comment: <property>
  <name>fetcher.server.min.delay</name>
  <value>0.5</value>
</property>


<property>
  <name>fetcher.threads.fetch</name>
  <value>400</value>
</property>

Comment: <property>
 <name>fetcher.max.crawl.delay</name>
 <value>10</value>
 <description>
 If the Crawl-Delay in robots.txt is set to greater than this value (in
 seconds) then the fetcher will skip this page, generating an error report.
 If set to -1 the fetcher will never skip such pages and will wait the
 amount of time retrieved from robots.txt Crawl-Delay, however long that
 might be.
 </description>
</property>

Comment: @kavetiraviteja can u help me what changes should I do to make it works and u said about proxy how to do it.

Comment: @RaviKiran can you please check my answer and please update your question with all the conf mentioned in comments

Answer (score 3):

As you requested In the comments

**How to Integrate proxy setup for Nutch?**

There are a lot of free(like https://www.sslproxies.org/) and paid(you can find many paid proxies online) proxy server that you can easily integrate to Nutch.

Nutch(1.16) has provided a lot of configurations that related to proxy server integration.

```
<property>
        <name>http.proxy.host</name>
        <value>ip-address</value>
        <description>The proxy hostname.  If empty, no proxy is used.</description>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>http.proxy.port</name>
        <value>proxy port</value>
        <description>The proxy port.</description>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>http.proxy.username</name>
        <value>blahblah</value>
        <description>Username for proxy. This will be used by
            'protocol-httpclient', if the proxy server requests basic, digest
            and/or NTLM authentication. To use this, 'protocol-httpclient' must
            be present in the value of 'plugin.includes' property.
            NOTE: For NTLM authentication, do not prefix the username with the
            domain, i.e. 'susam' is correct whereas 'DOMAIN\susam' is incorrect.
        </description>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>http.proxy.password</name>
        <value>blahblah</value>
        <description>Password for proxy. This will be used by
            'protocol-httpclient', if the proxy server requests basic, digest
            and/or NTLM authentication. To use this, 'protocol-httpclient' must
            be present in the value of 'plugin.includes' property.
        </description>
    </property>
<property>
        <name>http.proxy.realm</name>
        <value></value>
        <description>Authentication realm for proxy. Do not define a value
            if realm is not required or authentication should take place for any
            realm. NTLM does not use the notion of realms. Specify the domain name
            of NTLM authentication as the value for this property. To use this,
            'protocol-httpclient' must be present in the value of
            'plugin.includes' property.
        </description>
    </property>
<property>
        <name>http.proxy.type</name>
        <value>HTTP</value>
        <description>
            Proxy type: HTTP or SOCKS (cf. java.net.Proxy.Type).
            Note: supported by protocol-okhttp.
        </description>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>http.proxy.exception.list</name>
        <value>nutch.org,abc.com</value>
        <description>A comma separated list of hosts that don't use the proxy
            (e.g. intranets). Example: www.apache.org</description>
    </property>
```

If you see in nutch **lib-http plugin code** which is an interface plugin for all http libraries like(protocal-http,protocal-httpclient,protocal-okhttp .. etc)

```
org.apache.nutch.protocol.http.api.HttpBase
       public void setConf(Configuration conf) {
        this.conf = conf;
        this.proxyHost = conf.get("http.proxy.host");
        this.proxyPort = conf.getInt("http.proxy.port", 8080);
        this.proxyType = Proxy.Type.valueOf(conf.get("http.proxy.type", "HTTP"));
        this.proxyException = arrayToMap(conf.getStrings("http.proxy.exception.list"));
        this.useProxy = (proxyHost != null && proxyHost.length() > 0);
        this.timeout = conf.getInt("http.timeout", 10000);
        .........................................
        .........................................
```

as you can see from the above code Nutch uses those configurations while initializing **HTTPclient** object.

after taking a look at your **plugin.includes** conf you are using **protocol-httpclient**
if you look at the code of `**org.apache.nutch.protocol.httpclient.Http**` inside **configureClient** method

```
This particular specific code will integrate proxy server to httpclient
    // HTTP proxy server details
        if (useProxy) {
          hostConf.setProxy(proxyHost, proxyPort);
          if (proxyUsername.length() > 0) {
            AuthScope proxyAuthScope = getAuthScope(this.proxyHost, this.proxyPort,
                this.proxyRealm);
            NTCredentials proxyCredentials = new NTCredentials(this.proxyUsername,
                this.proxyPassword, Http.agentHost, this.proxyRealm);
            client.getState().setProxyCredentials(proxyAuthScope, proxyCredentials);
          }
        }
```

nutch is setting up proxy Object so that every request you make through httpclient will goes to the proxy server.

I would suggest you to increase fetcher.server.min.delay to 2 seconds.it will make sure the other end will not get abused.

For testing purpose, you can use [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NUTCH/SetupProxyForNutch) tutorial

Comment: @RaviKiran, please feel free to upvote or accept if it answers your question...

Answer (score 1):

It is issue of the http.agent.version they are blocking agent version after changing it solved the issues.